# Guice: how to print a module's bindings?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have been staring at a nasty bug in my code for the last 2 days, surrounding my Guice module and the bindings I've declared inside of it. I have about 20 bindings declared in my module, and only 1 of them is not working.

I have *exhausted* every option here and am wondering if there's a `module.print()`-like method in the Guice library where I can print out a String version of all a module's bindings; either that or somehow get Guice to log what's its doing whenever it reads in my defective binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(myModuleInstance);
Map<Key<?>,Binding<?>> map = injector.getBindings();
for(Entry<Key<?>, Binding<?>> e : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: you can use `map.entrySet()` to get key-value pairs without having to call `map.get(...)` in the loop.

Comment: There's also `Map::forEach`, e.g. `injector.getBindings().forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value))`

Answer (score 3):

herpylderp's solution should work in most cases. If you want to look at a Module by itself without creating an Injector (for example, if you have a configuration error that prevents you from constructing your Injector), you can use the Guice SPI tools to extract a list of bindings for a set of modules. It also lets you do plenty more beyond that, but that's beside the point ;)

See:
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ExtendingGuice#examples

In the listed example, they examine cases of static injection. For this case you could do the same, but instead override the `visit(Binding)` method of the `ElementVisitor`.

See also:
http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.2.2/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/spi/Elements.html

Also, note that each `Binding` has a `getSource()` method that may be useful in cases like this.

Note: I admit I haven't tried doing this *exact* thing before, so let me know if it does or doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The same as answer IAmYourFaja above but in a more modern style:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
String stringBinder = injector.getAllBindings().entrySet().stream()
            .map(e ->  e.getKey() + ": " +  e.getValue())
            .collect(joining("\n"));
```

Comment: that being said I believe that this requires all instances of getKey and getValue to have a toString() method.